# I'm not sure how to get this class to work

Tags: python

Hello im trying to make a chess game, however i cant seem to get this class to work, how to do i get the variable pawn_black1_status in the main block to change after i alter it in the class? If it works correctly it should print "dead"

```
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self,piece,pawn_black1_status):
        self.piece=piece
        self.pawn_black1_status=pawn_black1_status
    def Status2(self,piece,pawn_black1_status):
        self.piece=piece
        self.pawn_black1_status=pawn_black1_status
        self.pawn_black1_status="dead"
        
pawn_black1_status="alive"
Pawn1b_status=Status("p1b",pawn_black1_status)
Pawn1b_status.Status2("p1b",pawn_black1_status)
print(pawn_black1_status)
```

Comment: Your `Status` class does not update your `pawn_black1_status` variable.  That is just being used as the initial data when you create the class object.  Then, the class updates its own `pawn_black1_status` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference the class you have created to access the variable within it.

```py
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self,piece,pawn_black1_status):
        self.piece=piece
        self.pawn_black1_status=pawn_black1_status
    def Status2(self,piece,pawn_black1_status):
        self.piece=piece
        self.pawn_black1_status=pawn_black1_status
        self.pawn_black1_status="dead"
        
pawn_black1_status="alive"
Pawn1b_status=Status("p1b",pawn_black1_status)
Pawn1b_status.Status2("p1b",pawn_black1_status)
print(Pawn1b_status.pawn_black1_status)
```

Comment: If I have solved your issue, mark it as correct with that tick @Meyer